# Problem with a exercise two activity (codelabs guide)

Tags: android

Why The exercise is wrong and it does not go?
Exercise : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#2
My project: http://github.com/MatteoFavaroo/MatteoFavaro

Sorry for my english

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a minute to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your question to cover a specific issue.

Comment: Matteo welcome to stackoverflow - Please entice your viewers to view your code by at least uploading the raw files and not in rar.